# How to convert dispatch_time_t to CFAbsoluteTime or struct timespec?

Tags: ios, c, macos, grand-central-dispatch

While using Apple's grand central dispatch (GCD) for a timer one can see `dispatch_time_t` 64-bit integer that holds the time for GCD.

How do you convert its value to `CFAbsoluteTime` or `struct timespec` though?

Answer (score 1):

The `dispatch_time_t` is an opaque type. It [is defined](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/7fb9d5ceea562d60fe34ec55b6b165ae5aca38eb/dispatch/time.h#L59-L67) as:

> A somewhat abstract representation of time; where zero means “now” and `DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER` means “infinity” and every value in between is an opaque encoding.

I would not advise trying to convert it to another type. I would suggest going back to where you created this `dispatch_time_t` object, and creating your other type there.